# Best way to get to city center from Kyiv Boryspil Airport (KBP)

Tags: airport-transfer, ukraine, kbp

What is the best way from  Kyiv-Boryspil International Airport to the city center? Is there any public transport available?

Comment: Define "best"?..

Comment: Google gives https://www.kievkyivukraine.com/kiev/boryspil-airport-to-kiev-travel-bus-taxi.html

Comment: Best -> cheap, fast and safety

Answer (score 5):

[Sky Bus](http://skybus.kiev.ua/en/) is the most sensible way. It costs 80UAH from KBP to Railway Station.

Uber is also an option, approximately 300-380UAH depending on destination.

Answer (score 5):

The train easiest and may be the best, definetely the cheapest way, probably fastest, no trafic.
[image: Travel map to get to/from Kyiv city and Kyiv Boryspil airport]